# Is there a way I can apply a function to one specific sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, typeerror

Is there any way to apply this function to a sheet named "Production Log"?

```
function CopyDatatoLog() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Production Log');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B8:B11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 4);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 4,            spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A8:BL11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

I keep getting this error "TypeError: spreadsheet.getActive sheet is not a function". I'm not sure what I'm missing here. This function runs on a trigger and adds 4 rows above a specific row and then copy's and pastes 4 rows of data (just the values) into the added rows. This code does work in the sheet as long as i'm active in it but as soon as I added in the getSheetByName, It stopped working. If any one has any advice or can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `spreadsheet` is defined in your first line of code as the sheet called "Production Log". As such, when you are using `spreadsheet`, you are not actually calling the spreadsheet, but that sheet in particular.

Since you want to apply your changes to a particular defined sheet, you no longer need the `getActiveSheet()` function.  You can simply use `spreadsheet.insertRowsBefore()`.

The following line:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 4);
```

should therefore be changed to:

```
spreadsheet.insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 4);
```

and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thank you.  You are right.  Have since modified my answer.